# Windows XP Login Screen Revival

Tags: windows, windows-xp, networking, login-screen

Recently my windows XP (SP2) login screen is replaced by a dialog box at startup.I want to get the old login screen back. I don't know how it was modified but i guess technical representative from the broadband company messed up with something in network settings and somehow i'm getting prompt instead of login screen.

I want to get the old login screen instead of that ugly dialog box. is there anyway to fix this ?

Comment: Why are you still running SP2?!!?

Comment: @Shinrai, One of my old software(local language converter) is having issues with SP3, so rolled back to SP2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.) Control Panel > Users > Change the way users log on or off, see if "use welcome screen" and "use fast user switching is ticked, if not ticked, tick them.

> Note: If both choices are not available to be ticked, the PC is part of a Domain and you cannot change this behavior.
>
> If the PC is part of a Domain or you only have the Administrator account to log into (no regular user account) fast user switching cannot be enabled, or the control userpasswords setting is ticked, see #2

.
[image]

.
[image]

.

2.) If that does not get it back or they are already ticked, then open a run command, type in "control userpasswords2" without the quotes, if the box at the top is ticked, Untick it and hit OK
.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Open the Control Panel and go to *User Accounts*.  Select *Change the way users log on or off*.  Turn on *Use the Welcome screen*.  You might also want to re-enable *Fast User Switching* if you use that, as well.

[image: Windows XP User Accounts logon options]